# How to assign Zend_Navigator to the view?

Tags: php, templates, zend-framework, zend-navigation

I tried using Zend_Registry but it doesn't output anything
then I tried this in my default module bootstrap

```
public function _initNavigation()
{
    $this->bootstrap('layout');
    $layout = $this->getResource('layout');
    $view = $layout->getView();
```

But it says `'Resource matching "layout" not found'`. Since I have two modules and I'm already using Zend_Navigation in the admin module, I don't know how to get over with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You first have to create your layout resource.

Here is how i did it:

```
  $navigation = new Zend_Config_Xml(APPLICATION_PATH.'/configs/navigation.xml','nav');
                $navContainer = new Zend_Navigation($navigation);
                $this->_view->navigation($navContainer);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$container = new Zend_Navigation(
    Zend_Registry::get('configuration')->navigation
);
$actionController->view->navigation($container);
```

That should be enough.

In the config ini file you could have something like:

```
;NAVIGATION
navigation.index.label = Index
navigation.index.module = index
navigation.index.controller = index
navigation.index.action = index
navigation.page1.label = Page 1
navigation.page1.module = index
navigation.page1.controller = pages
navigation.page1.action = page-1
```